# How to implment usb reverse tethering in android application?

Tags: android

As per requirement need to access data from PC to Android device.With the help of reverse tethering we can do it.

Please suggest the way that how to do reverse tethering in application.

Comment: Go to this link: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2287494. Hope this will help...

Comment: Wanted to eanable usb reverse tethering via code.

Comment: I never try this as per documentation it can work by enabling USB Tethering when device is attach to PC. Moreover you need rooted access to use this api.

Comment: can you please tell me any api which helps to usb reverse tethering? can we do it within code so that application enables it internally without user interaction.